# How to fix "A reference to 'Audio Precision AP2700 3.00 Object Library' could not be added"

Tags: c#, audio

I am having some dll related problems with C# in visual studio 2013. I can get this AP Hardware demo to run, but I cannot get the dll imported into my own project, or re-imported into the demo for that matter. I think I am doing something wrong from a visual studio standpoint.

I am using the AP2700 demo found here: http://www.ap.com/download/api It runs fine out of the box through visual studio, but I cannot figure out how the "AP" reference is added in the example project. The "Audio Precision AP2700 3.00 Object Library" is checked in the COM references, but when I remove it and try to add it again, I get an error: "A reference to 'Audio Precision AP2700 3.00 Object Library' could not be added."

Here's a picture of the example project, works fine

[image]
[image]

Here's a picture of removing the dll then trying to re-add the dll

[image]

Below are the properties of the AP reference:
[image]

It turns out the solution is there is another .dll to add, called Interop.AP.dll. After this is added, it will give some errors related to embedded interop. Go into properties and turn embedded interop to false. Does anyone know why the name doesn't match? "Interop.AP" vs the original "AP"?

[image]

Comment: what is the property for the .`AP` .dll in the project set to in regards to the 'CopyToLocal` did you also add this to the `using` in the .cs file header..?

Comment: Could that be due to a .net version mismatch, such as you're project is set to run on a .net platform and the dll you select from another ? --- EDIT --- Never mind I saw that it is a COM dll. However could it be a 64 vs 32 bits assembly mismatch ?

Answer (score 0):

The example project doesn't reference the COM library directly but instead references a primary interop assembly in the bin folder `Interop.AP.dll`.  I think the add COM reference dialog might be choking on the reference to the original COM object due to fact that is an executable instead of a DLL.

If you want to recreate the primary interop assembly you can do so with the tlbimp tool.

Run the VS2013 command line tools:

```
> cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Audio Precision\AP2700
> tlbimp ap2700.exe/1 /out:c:\tmp\Interop.AP.dll
```

Now you can add it the reference to the newly created interop assembly using as a normal .NET reference.

Don't forget to set embed to false in the reference's properties.

Also, to respond to one of the comments, I don't believe 64-bit would be a problem (AP2700 software is 32-bit) since the COM is happening out of process.